# How to print value using prompt with if else statement?

Tags: javascript

```js
var age = '16';
prompt(enter 'age');
if (age > 17) {
  alert("good to drive");
} else {
  alert("sorry you are not eligible");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a few syntax errors but here's a patched up version:

```js
var age = prompt("Please enter your age"); // Gets input
if (age > 17) {
  alert("Good to drive.");
} else {
  alert("Sorry you are not eligible.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines should be:

```
var age = prompt('enter age');
```

The whole argument to `prompt()` has to be in quotes, and you need to assign the result to the variable so you can use it in the `if` statement.